# how to pass jquery row value one page to other page

Tags: jquery

Using this jquery code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m1">Get Selected id's</a> 

    jQuery("#m1").click( function() { var s; 
    s = jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'); alert(s); });
```

Double click evnt on the jquery grid row:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
                   $("#tabs").tabs('enable', 1);
                   var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
                    var selected = $tabs.tabs('select', 1);
                   },
```

I am getting the row value, here my question is on double click on each row I am going to second controller, there in second controller I need to get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting a value in another page from the previous you can use $.cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

and then get it from cookie in the second page.

you need the [jq cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) though